# In a d3 line chart, how do I create a bounding box behind my text that is the same size as what I'm mousing over?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using d3 v4.  I want to create a rollover for my line chart such that the information that is displayed for each point is completely captured by a background box that is the same size as the text.  I'm confused about how to do this, though.  I'm creating the SVG element like so

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

...

  var rect = focus.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .attr("fill", "yellow");

  var text = focus.append("text")
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("y", 10);

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
      .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
      .on("mousemove", mousemove);

  function mousemove() {
    var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
    focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.index_date) + "," + y(d.value) + ")");
    var descriptor = d.value + "\n" + d.index_date
    focus.select("text").text(descriptor);
  }
```

I'm having a couple of problems, though.  First the bounding box is of fixed dimensions, so it is not capturing the text.  Second, my new line seems to be getting ignored in my text.  Ideally, I want two lines, one with a value and the second with a date.  The Fiddle that illustrates what I have so far -- https://jsfiddle.net/8reo2Lvc/1/ .  How do I create the bounding box that is the same size as the text it is surrounding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the new line problem, you cannot break a SVG text element using `"\n"`. Instead of that, append a `<tspan>`:

```
focus.select("text")
    .text(d.value)
    .append("tspan")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("dy", "1.5em")
    .text(d.index_date);
```

Now, back to the bounding box problem. A simple approach is getting the bounding box of the text element:

```
var bbox = focus.select("text").node().getBBox();
```

And use it to set the width and height of the rectangle:

```
rect.attr("width", bbox.width)
    .attr("height", bbox.height)
```

Here is the updated fiddle with those changes: https://jsfiddle.net/yw46ycse/